# How do I dump only results of one table in a database in MySQL and replicate to another remote empty table with the same structure?

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

It's a long sentence, anyone knows?

Answer (score 3):

To create the `dump`:

```
mysqldump --user [username] --password=[password] --no-create-info [database name] [table name] > /tmp/dump.sql
```

To restore:

```
mysql --u [username] --password=[password] [database name] [table name] < /tmp/dump.sql
```

Comment: The only obvious caveat in the restore is foreign key relationships. But i don't see any solution to that.

Comment: `[table name]` is not necessary in the restore part.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table_name [IN externaldatabase]
FROM old_tablename
WHERE 1=0
```

I'm not sure this works with My SQL but you get the idea.

This DOES NOT duplicate PK, FK, Indexes, Stored Procedures, or anything else. Just the columns and data types.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_select_into.asp)

D'oh

I must have misunderstood your question. It is almost 3am way past bedtime.

Ok so there is probably a better way to do this, but this would get the job done.

```
SELECT  CONCAT('INSERT INTO (COL1, COL2) VALUES (',COL1,COL2,');');
```

You will need to add ' for some data types so.

```
SELECT  CONCAT('INSERT INTO (COL1, COL2) VALUES (',COL1,''' ''',COL2,');');
```

The take the output and run on the remote db.

Comment: The new_table is on another machine.So I think I have to do it in 2 steps.